# Unable to change the color of UISearchBar

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I'm using `UISearchBar` in my app its look likes below
 [image]

I want `UISearchBar` color to be clear color i tried the following
        `search.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`
but the result is same can any one help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Try tintColor:

```
    search.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    searchBar.barTintColor = color; //for iOS 7
} else {
    searchBar.tintColor = color; //for earlier than iOS 7
}
```